# Error selecting range from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to select a range located on the 1st sheet of an Excel workbook, whether it is active or not.

```
Set WorkRng = Sheets(1).Range(Cells(9, 4), Cells(39, colNum))
```

This is returning the error:

```
Run-time error: 1004
Application-defined or object-defined error
```

Only when the 1st sheet isn't selected

Note: colNum = 11

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Thanks, I get the error: 1004 - Select method of Range class failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your on the right track in that you are using an explicit sheet object (which is good). Where it breaks down is how you assign your Range object.

Your code says

```
Set WorkRng = Sheets(1)   <-- use sheet "1" as the reference for generating the range
      .Range(
       Cells(9, 4)        <-- compose the range starting with cells R9C4 in the *Activesheet*
      , Cells(39, colNum) <-- end the range composure with cells R29C[colnum] in the *Activesheet*
      )
```

You need yo qualify ALL your range references

```
Set WorkRng = Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).Cells(9, 4), Sheets(1).Cells(39, colNum))
```

Or alternatively

```
With Sheets(1) 
    Set WorkRng = .Range(.Cells(9, 4), .Cells(39, colNum))
End With
```

Notice the `.` before `Range` and `Cells`. This means they are all being taken from the same sheet. Otherwise it is illogical.